# Compute vectors from hand-drawn artifacts in images (no text recognition involved)

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, vector-graphics, raster

Please note that this question has nothing to do with hand-writing recognition. The user could draw random doodles for all I care. What I want to achieve is to extract a set of vectors from the image that can then be used to generate scalable approximations of the same drawing.

I mention hand-writing/drawing specifically because it involves a vector-friendly operation rather than any arbitrary image (in which case a simple raster scaling algorithm would do).

Once vectors are extracted, you could then represent them in any number of ways such as SVG, etc. Looking for something simple to get started with. I'd be happy to hear any suggestions irrespective of programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're looking for raster-to-vector conversion, which is a feature of e.g. Photoshop. Google finds lots of hits but there is some GPL C++ code [on the first link of this page](http://www.xmailserver.org/davide.html). Also take a look at [this Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_raster-to-vector_conversion_software) for some more options.

Although they are C/C++ rather than C#, you did say you don't mind about the programming language, so I would look first at:

- Potrace ([Wiki page here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potrace) and [web site here](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/)), and
- Inkscape ([Wiki page here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkscape)), which uses Potrace and also supports SVG

Both of the above are open source and cross platform so the code should be generic enough for conversion to C# if necessary. The main Potrace page lists an existing C# conversion called [Vectorization](http://www.drawing3d.de/Downloads.aspx). Alternatively you could consider making a C++/CLI assembly to access the native code from .NET.

From the Potrace example, page, you can see the kind of conversion possible:

[image: potrace]

Comment: The C# port of Potrace is brilliant and will serve as a very good learning point. Thank you!